# Proving an equation help.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I wanted to prove the following statment.

$\frac {n^3}{3} + \frac {n^2}{2} + \frac {n}{6}$ is an integer for any $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$.

I didn't really understand how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** Write
$$
\frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac n6 = 
\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
Now, it suffices to prove that $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is a multiple of $6$.  To that end, show that among the numbers $n,n+1,2n+1$:

- At least one will be even
- At least one will be a multiple of $3$

Comment: If we knew this is the sum of the first $n$ squares, we'd be done. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 =\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}= \frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}
\end{eqnarray*}
The left hand side is clearly an integer ... & therefore so is the right hand side.